# "ValueError: Shape of passed values is ... indices imply ..." when applying functools.partial to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I saw many people posting problems related to this kind of error, yet none of the solutions I browsed did fit to my problem, which is the following:

```
def get_dynamics_for_window(dynamics_predictions, window_size, input_PTM_entry):
    # function returns a numpy array
    # dyanmics_predictions argument is a big dictionary of lists
    ...

get_dynamics_partial = functools.partial(get_dynamics_for_window, dynamics_predictions, args.window_size)
# input_PTM_df is a DataFrame returning .shape equal to "(1553, 5)" at this line
array_extensions = input_PTM_df.apply(get_dynamics_partial, axis=1)
```

Then I get the error below on the last line from the above snippet.

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1553,), indices imply (1553, 5)

I looked at several discussions related to such error messages, yet I have no clue about what's really the problem and how to debug it.

Comment: The provided code does not permit to reproduce the problem. We need the content of the function. For example the same error is thrown by this code `DataFrame(np.random.randn(1553, 5), columns=['A'])`. Saying that the shape of data (1553 rows  and 5 columns) does not match the shape of the index (1553 rows and 1 column).

Comment: Note that shapes of `(1553,)` and `(1553,1)` do not represent identical arrays.  You might need to add a `reshape()` somewhere.